# php append to json array from new array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a little problem over here:

All I want to display is:

```
{"accounts":
{"n":"1001","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"},
{"n":"1002","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"}, 
{"n":"1005","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"}
}
```

At the beginning I have a simple empty database row with no content. Then I want to run this script:

```
$accountff["accounts"] = array( 'n' => 1002, 
                            'd' => 2018-07-02,
                            'u' => ,
                            'e' => ,
                            'r' => );

$txid_json = json_encode($accountff, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

This works fine, the output is:

```
{"accounts":{"n":1002,"d":"2018-07-02","u":"","e":"","r":""}}
```

But every time I want to add a new "account" with this script:

```
  $account['n'] = $post_id;
  $account['d'] = date('Y-m-d');
  $mysqljson = json_decode($user_accounts,true);
  array_push($mysqljson['accounts'], $account); 
  $txid_json = json_encode($mysqljson, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

(The variable `$user_accounts` is the column where the JSON is saved.)

The output is:

```
{"accounts":{"n":1002,"d":"2018-07-02","u":"","e":"","r":"","0":{"n":1002,"d":"2018-07-02","u":"","e":"","r":""}}}
```

That actually drives me crazy... I don't know where the "0" is coming from.

Comment: It comes from using `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`.. all keys must be numeric and in order 0-n for no keys to show.

Comment: even if i delete json_force_object in the last script there's a '0'

Comment: use jsonlint, you can see its no longer an array of objects so it breaks..

Answer (score 0):

What you show is not valid JSON. Everything inside an object must be `key: value` pairs, but you have no keys for the objects except the first one.

It looks like you really want the `accounts` property to be an array of accounts, so it should be:

```
$accountff["accounts"] = array(
    array( 'n' => 1002, 
            'd' => 2018-07-02,
            'u' => ,
            'e' => ,
            'r' => )
);
```

Then to add a new account, you do:

```
$accountff["accounts"][] = $account;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
array_push($accountff["accounts"], $account);
```

The JSON will look like this:

```
{"accounts": [
    {"n":"1001","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"},
    {"n":"1002","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"}, 
    {"n":"1005","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"}
    ]
}
```

If you use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` it will look like this:

```
{"accounts": {
    "0": {"n":"1001","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"},
    "1": {"n":"1002","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"}, 
    "2": {"n":"1005","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Barma, thx for the explanation. Even tho i still get this output on second entry: ´{"accounts":{"n":"1001","d":"2018-06-30","u":"","e":"","r":"123112","0":{"n":1001,"d":"2018-07-03","u":" ","e":" ","r":" "}}}´. I'm using json array now, not json object.

Comment: You must still be missing `[]` after `$accountff["accounts"]`.

Comment: Do you understand that `$array[] = x` is the same as `array_push($array, x)`?